# make background of label change on checked state of input

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm making a React Styled-Components toggle component. It's almost finished, but I'm just not getting that last part. This is what I have:

[image]
[image]

So when the input has a checked state, I want to have a light grey G logo where the colored G logo was. This is my code:

```
---------VIEW:
import React from "react";

import { SwitchInput, SwitchLabel, SwitchButton } from "./toggle-style";

const Switch = ({ id, toggled, onChange }) => (
  <>
    <SwitchInput
      id={id}
      type="checkbox"
      checked={toggled}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
    <SwitchLabel htmlFor={id}>
      <SwitchButton />
    </SwitchLabel>
  </>
);

export default Switch;

----------STYLING:
import styled from "styled-components";

import googleIcon from "../../../assets/images/google-icon.svg";
import googleIconGrey from "../../../assets/images/google-icon-grey.svg";
import facebookIcon from "../../../assets/images/facebook-icon.svg";
import facebookIconGrey from "../../../assets/images/facebook-icon-grey.svg";

export const SwitchInput = styled.input`
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
`;

export const SwitchLabel = styled.label`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 82px;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-image: url(${facebookIconGrey});
  background-position: 75% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 0.2s;
  ${SwitchInput}:checked & {
    background-image: url(${googleIconGrey});
    background-position: 25% 50%;
  }
`;

export const SwitchButton = styled.span`
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  left: 6px;
  top: calc(50% - 16px);
  border-radius: 45px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: grey;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-image: url(${googleIcon});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  ${SwitchInput}:checked + ${SwitchLabel} & {
    left: calc(100% - 6px);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background-image: url(${facebookIcon});
  }
`;
```

All credits to this author, since I got most of the code from his/her Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-styled-components-toggle-switch-3ft38

Answer (score 0):

```
import styled from "styled-components";

import googleIcon from "../../../assets/images/google-icon.svg";
import googleIconGrey from "../../../assets/images/google-icon-grey.svg";
import facebookIcon from "../../../assets/images/facebook-icon.svg";
import facebookIconGrey from "../../../assets/images/facebook-icon-grey.svg";

export const SwitchLabel = styled.label`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 82px;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-image: url(${facebookIconGrey});
  background-position: 75% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: 0.2s;
`;

export const SwitchInput = styled.input`
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  &:checked + ${SwitchLabel} {
    background-image: url(${googleIconGrey});
    background-position: 20% 50%;
  }
`;

export const SwitchButton = styled.span`
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  left: 6px;
  top: calc(50% - 16px);
  border-radius: 45px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: grey;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-image: url(${googleIcon});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  ${SwitchInput}:checked + ${SwitchLabel} & {
    left: calc(100% - 6px);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background-image: url(${facebookIcon});
  }
`;
```

Comment: It's probably better to give an explanation about what have you added / fixed..